# sipjs and asterisk voice call no audio issue

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, sip

I am using sipjs 0.7.5 version and asterisk 13.12.1 to established call between 2 sipjs call through webRTC. Both sipjs client and asterisk server are in local network. I am giving asterisk log of both sip messages and rtp packet bellow:

My problem is from log I am seeing that RTP packet is getting sent to both end via ICE. but in client browser no audio is playing. i.e. there is no audio in browser.

```
            <--- SIP read from WS:192.168.40.48:10380 --->
        INVITE sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060 SIP/2.0
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.208;branch=z9hG4bK4771627
        Max-Forwards: 70
        To: <sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060>
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45:5060>;tag=dc2e904hed
        Call-ID: iu2sjhg9scpcrir0slju
        CSeq: 8911 INVITE
        Contact: <sip:haitt3bm@192.0.2.208;transport=ws;ob>
        Allow: ACK,CANCEL,INVITE,MESSAGE,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY,REFER
        Content-Type: application/sdp
        Supported: outbound
        User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.5
        Content-Length: 1220

        v=0
        o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-49.0.2 2371358821422302787 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
        s=-
        t=0 0
        a=sendrecv
        a=fingerprint:sha-256 DD:4B:CC:5D:70:15:CE:34:6B:A7:AF:2A:F8:AA:E8:B8:00:C3:28:F6:C8:9C:03:F5:E6:69:04:D6:81:11:3B:85
        a=ice-options:trickle
        a=msid-semantic:WMS *
        m=audio 55294 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8
        c=IN IP4 192.168.35.1
        a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.35.1 55294 typ host
        a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.221.1 55295 typ host
        a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2122121471 192.168.40.48 55296 typ host
        a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 192.168.35.1 55297 typ host
        a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2122187006 192.168.221.1 55298 typ host
        a=candidate:2 2 UDP 2122121470 192.168.40.48 55299 typ host
        a=sendrecv
        a=end-of-candidates
        a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
        a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1
        a=ice-pwd:43428b6027fb801be25dae4fdf05981a
        a=ice-ufrag:84b4daa9
        a=mid:sdparta_0
        a=msid:{aaa3da10-5310-4167-b4b7-8328a8e5ba84} {4bee853d-06c4-4bfd-ae69-319a1994c844}
        a=rtcp:55297 IN IP4 192.168.35.1
        a=rtcp-mux
        a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
        a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
        a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
        a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
        a=setup:actpass
        a=ssrc:1072212720 cname:{a978e140-65a4-49e8-bb8b-2273ab1b6026}
        <------------->
        --- (13 headers 32 lines) ---
        Using INVITE request as basis request - iu2sjhg9scpcrir0slju
        Found peer '1062' for '1062' from 192.168.40.48:10380
          == DTLS ECDH initialized (automatic), faster PFS enabled
          == DTLS ECDH initialized (automatic), faster PFS enabled
          == Using SIP VIDEO CoS mark 6
          == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
        [Nov  2 10:07:30] NOTICE[64407][C-00000008]: chan_sip.c:10315 process_sdp: Received SAVPF profle in audio offer but AVPF is not enabled, enabling: audio 55294 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8
        Found RTP audio format 109
        Found RTP audio format 9
        Found RTP audio format 0
        Found RTP audio format 8
        Found audio description format opus for ID 109
        Found audio description format G722 for ID 9
        Found audio description format PCMU for ID 0
        Found audio description format PCMA for ID 8
        Capabilities: us - (ulaw|alaw|gsm|h263), peer - audio=(ulaw|alaw|g722|opus)/video=(nothing)/text=(nothing), combined - (ulaw|alaw)
        Non-codec capabilities (dtmf): us - 0x1 (telephone-event|), peer - 0x0 (nothing), combined - 0x0 (nothing)
        Peer audio RTP is at port 192.168.35.1:55294
        Peer doesn't provide video
        Looking for 1063 in default (domain 192.168.40.45)
        sip_route_dump: route/path hop: <sip:haitt3bm@192.0.2.208;transport=ws;ob>

        <--- Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.168.40.48:5060 --->
        SIP/2.0 100 Trying
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.208;branch=z9hG4bK4771627;received=192.168.40.48
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45:5060>;tag=dc2e904hed
        To: <sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060>
        Call-ID: iu2sjhg9scpcrir0slju
        CSeq: 8911 INVITE
        Server: Asterisk PBX 13.12.1
        Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
        Supported: replaces, timer
        Contact: <sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060;transport=WS>
        Content-Length: 0


        <------------>
            -- Executing [1063@default:1] Dial("SIP/1062-00000010", "SIP/1063") in new stack
          == DTLS ECDH initialized (automatic), faster PFS enabled
          == DTLS ECDH initialized (automatic), faster PFS enabled
          == Using SIP VIDEO CoS mark 6
          == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
        Audio is at 14284
        Adding codec ulaw to SDP
        Adding codec alaw to SDP
        Adding codec gsm to SDP
        Adding non-codec 0x1 (telephone-event) to SDP
        Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.168.40.48:10383:
        INVITE sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws SIP/2.0
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.40.45:5060;branch=z9hG4bK3f05c747
        Max-Forwards: 70
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45>;tag=as0cfcb1f6
        To: <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws>
        Contact: <sip:1062@192.168.40.45:5060;transport=WS>
        Call-ID: 30d68fec7f1ab1ad5f413e2031ad3290@192.168.40.45:5060
        CSeq: 102 INVITE
        User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 13.12.1
        Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 04:07:32 GMT
        Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
        Supported: replaces, timer
        Content-Type: application/sdp
        Content-Length: 878

        v=0
        o=root 1773642892 1773642892 IN IP4 192.168.40.45
        s=Asterisk PBX 13.12.1
        c=IN IP4 192.168.40.45
        t=0 0
        m=audio 14284 RTP/SAVP 0 8 3 101
        a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
        a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
        a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
        a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
        a=fmtp:101 0-16
        a=maxptime:150
        a=ice-ufrag:72465290354ec1f13cdfbb24592c36f1
        a=ice-pwd:2e3f757f3f18a66e4ce88b32509c65d3
        a=candidate:Hc0a8282d 1 UDP 2130706431 192.168.40.45 14284 typ host
        a=candidate:Sb6a06f32 1 UDP 1694498815 182.160.111.50 14284 typ srflx raddr 192.168.40.45 rport 14284
        a=candidate:Hc0a8282d 2 UDP 2130706430 192.168.40.45 14285 typ host
        a=candidate:Sb6a06f32 2 UDP 1694498814 182.160.111.50 14285 typ srflx raddr 192.168.40.45 rport 14285
        a=connection:new
        a=setup:actpass
        a=fingerprint:SHA-256 4B:8C:EF:A9:7A:59:B0:3A:73:B2:BF:70:4D:EC:94:B4:03:BD:FA:5C:E0:50:F8:CD:5B:52:CC:21:5E:D2:32:D4
        a=sendrecv

        ---
            -- Called SIP/1063

        <--- SIP read from WS:192.168.40.48:10383 --->
        SIP/2.0 100 Trying
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.40.45:5060;branch=z9hG4bK3f05c747
        To: <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws>
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45>;tag=as0cfcb1f6
        Call-ID: 30d68fec7f1ab1ad5f413e2031ad3290@192.168.40.45:5060
        CSeq: 102 INVITE
        Supported: outbound
        User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.5
        Content-Length: 0

        <------------->
        --- (9 headers 0 lines) ---

        <--- SIP read from WS:192.168.40.48:10383 --->
        SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.40.45:5060;branch=z9hG4bK3f05c747
        To: <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws>;tag=iliacjnojs
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45>;tag=as0cfcb1f6
        Call-ID: 30d68fec7f1ab1ad5f413e2031ad3290@192.168.40.45:5060
        CSeq: 102 INVITE
        Contact: <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws>
        Supported: outbound
        User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.5
        Content-Length: 0

        <------------->
        --- (10 headers 0 lines) ---
        sip_route_dump: route/path hop: <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws>
            -- SIP/1063-00000011 is ringing

        <--- Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.168.40.48:5060 --->
        SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.208;branch=z9hG4bK4771627;received=192.168.40.48
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45:5060>;tag=dc2e904hed
        To: <sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060>;tag=as6443d323
        Call-ID: iu2sjhg9scpcrir0slju
        CSeq: 8911 INVITE
        Server: Asterisk PBX 13.12.1
        Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
        Supported: replaces, timer
        Contact: <sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060;transport=WS>
        Content-Length: 0


        <------------>

        <--- SIP read from WS:192.168.40.48:10383 --->
        SIP/2.0 200 OK
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.40.45:5060;branch=z9hG4bK3f05c747
        To: <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws>;tag=iliacjnojs
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45>;tag=as0cfcb1f6
        Call-ID: 30d68fec7f1ab1ad5f413e2031ad3290@192.168.40.45:5060
        CSeq: 102 INVITE
        Contact: <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws>
        Allow: ACK,CANCEL,INVITE,MESSAGE,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY,REFER
        Supported: outbound
        User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.5
        Content-Type: application/sdp
        Content-Length: 2050

        v=0
        o=- 8316228832686210830 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
        s=-
        t=0 0
        a=msid-semantic: WMS Lezzrl9JzDRw0rDdgktZDKQiqy9HrSw4vQzI
        m=audio 55300 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVP 0 8 101
        c=IN IP4 192.168.35.1
        a=rtcp:55303 IN IP4 192.168.35.1
        a=candidate:1468545711 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.35.1 55300 typ host generation 0 network-id 3
        a=candidate:4198037383 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.221.1 55301 typ host generation 0 network-id 2
        a=candidate:235970510 1 udp 2122129151 192.168.40.48 55302 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
        a=candidate:1468545711 2 udp 2122260222 192.168.35.1 55303 typ host generation 0 network-id 3
        a=candidate:4198037383 2 udp 2122194686 192.168.221.1 55304 typ host generation 0 network-id 2
        a=candidate:235970510 2 udp 2122129150 192.168.40.48 55305 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
        a=candidate:420202079 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.35.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 3
        a=candidate:3032157047 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.221.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2
        a=candidate:1083401022 1 tcp 1518149375 192.168.40.48 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
        a=candidate:420202079 2 tcp 1518280446 192.168.35.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 3
        a=candidate:3032157047 2 tcp 1518214910 192.168.221.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2
        a=candidate:1083401022 2 tcp 1518149374 192.168.40.48 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
        a=ice-ufrag:Y4fJ
        a=ice-pwd:v8rrrqGJU+aLsIg34kJbx9KL
        a=fingerprint:sha-256 E0:34:1F:A5:DC:CA:56:F1:D1:70:61:DD:7F:F6:7A:34:F0:D7:9D:53:EF:22:0C:AB:09:63:B9:F5:1F:63:E4:E3
        a=setup:active
        a=mid:audio
        a=sendrecv
        a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
        a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
        a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
        a=ssrc:4040961807 cname:zubAX2k8KRNEKsTO
        a=ssrc:4040961807 msid:Lezzrl9JzDRw0rDdgktZDKQiqy9HrSw4vQzI b17cfaa5-2826-4bce-9f23-be489c523d03
        a=ssrc:4040961807 mslabel:Lezzrl9JzDRw0rDdgktZDKQiqy9HrSw4vQzI
        a=ssrc:4040961807 label:b17cfaa5-2826-4bce-9f23-be489c523d03
        <------------->
        --- (12 headers 33 lines) ---
        Found RTP audio format 0
        Found RTP audio format 8
        Found RTP audio format 101
        Found audio description format PCMU for ID 0
        Found audio description format PCMA for ID 8
        Found audio description format telephone-event for ID 101
        Capabilities: us - (ulaw|alaw|gsm|h263), peer - audio=(ulaw|alaw)/video=(nothing)/text=(nothing), combined - (ulaw|alaw)
        Non-codec capabilities (dtmf): us - 0x1 (telephone-event|), peer - 0x1 (telephone-event|), combined - 0x1 (telephone-event|)
        Peer audio RTP is at port 192.168.35.1:55300
        sip_route_dump: route/path hop: <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws>
        set_destination: Parsing <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws> for address/port to send to
        set_destination: URI is for WebSocket, we can't set destination
        Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.0.2.218:5060:
        ACK sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws SIP/2.0
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.40.45:5060;branch=z9hG4bK52a8c1f1
        Max-Forwards: 70
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45>;tag=as0cfcb1f6
        To: <sip:thqqcmh6@192.0.2.218;transport=ws>;tag=iliacjnojs
        Contact: <sip:1062@192.168.40.45:5060;transport=WS>
        Call-ID: 30d68fec7f1ab1ad5f413e2031ad3290@192.168.40.45:5060
        CSeq: 102 ACK
        User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 13.12.1
        Content-Length: 0


        ---
            -- SIP/1063-00000011 answered SIP/1062-00000010
        Audio is at 11134
        Adding codec ulaw to SDP
        Adding codec alaw to SDP

        <--- Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.168.40.48:5060 --->
        SIP/2.0 200 OK
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.208;branch=z9hG4bK4771627;received=192.168.40.48
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45:5060>;tag=dc2e904hed
        To: <sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060>;tag=as6443d323
        Call-ID: iu2sjhg9scpcrir0slju
        CSeq: 8911 INVITE
        Server: Asterisk PBX 13.12.1
        Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
        Supported: replaces, timer
        Contact: <sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060;transport=WS>
        Content-Type: application/sdp
        Content-Length: 797

        v=0
        o=root 562796326 562796326 IN IP4 192.168.40.45
        s=Asterisk PBX 13.12.1
        c=IN IP4 192.168.40.45
        t=0 0
        m=audio 11134 RTP/SAVPF 0 8
        a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
        a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
        a=maxptime:150
        a=ice-ufrag:58d669ea38ed577755928de05ad017a0
        a=ice-pwd:4513e77c0ac114a14e1f9a654764e1e9
        a=candidate:Hc0a8282d 1 UDP 2130706431 192.168.40.45 11134 typ host
        a=candidate:Sb6a06f32 1 UDP 1694498815 182.160.111.50 11134 typ srflx raddr 192.168.40.45 rport 11134
        a=candidate:Hc0a8282d 2 UDP 2130706430 192.168.40.45 11135 typ host
        a=candidate:Sb6a06f32 2 UDP 1694498814 182.160.111.50 11135 typ srflx raddr 192.168.40.45 rport 11135
        a=connection:new
        a=setup:active
        a=fingerprint:SHA-256 4B:8C:EF:A9:7A:59:B0:3A:73:B2:BF:70:4D:EC:94:B4:03:BD:FA:5C:E0:50:F8:CD:5B:52:CC:21:5E:D2:32:D4
        a=sendrecv

        <------------>
            -- Channel SIP/1063-00000011 joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <047baea4-91e3-43fa-99ec-5b49d10b595c>
            -- Channel SIP/1062-00000010 joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <047baea4-91e3-43fa-99ec-5b49d10b595c>
               > 0x7f243407b350 -- Probation passed - setting RTP source address to 192.168.40.48:55302
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012779, ts 909638055, len 000160)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012780, ts 909638215, len 000160)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012781, ts 909638375, len 000160)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012782, ts 909638535, len 000160)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012783, ts 909638695, len 000160)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012784, ts 909638855, len 000160)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012785, ts 909639015, len 000160)

        <--- SIP read from WS:192.168.40.48:10380 --->
        ACK sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060;transport=ws SIP/2.0
        Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.208;branch=z9hG4bK6228050
        Max-Forwards: 70
        To: <sip:1063@192.168.40.45:5060>;tag=as6443d323
        From: "1062" <sip:1062@192.168.40.45:5060>;tag=dc2e904hed
        Call-ID: iu2sjhg9scpcrir0slju
        CSeq: 8911 ACK
        Supported: outbound
        User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.5
        Content-Length: 0

        <------------->
        --- (10 headers 0 lines) ---
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012786, ts 909639175, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.35.1:55294 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006802, ts 909639168, len 000160)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012787, ts 909639335, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55296 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006803, ts 909639328, len 000170)
               > 0x7f24340788f0 -- Probation passed - setting RTP source address to 192.168.40.48:55296
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55296 (type 00, seq 029688, ts 3658919058, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55302 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 024034, ts 3658919056, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012788, ts 909639495, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55296 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006804, ts 909639488, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55296 (type 00, seq 029689, ts 3658919218, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55302 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 024035, ts 3658919216, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012789, ts 909639655, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55296 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006805, ts 909639648, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55296 (type 00, seq 029690, ts 3658919378, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55302 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 024036, ts 3658919376, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012790, ts 909639815, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55296 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006806, ts 909639808, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55296 (type 00, seq 029691, ts 3658919538, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55302 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 024037, ts 3658919536, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012791, ts 909639975, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55296 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006807, ts 909639968, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55296 (type 00, seq 029692, ts 3658919698, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55302 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 024038, ts 3658919696, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012792, ts 909640135, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55296 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006808, ts 909640128, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55296 (type 00, seq 029693, ts 3658919858, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55302 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 024039, ts 3658919856, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012793, ts 909640295, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55296 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006809, ts 909640288, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55296 (type 00, seq 029694, ts 3658920018, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55302 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 024040, ts 3658920016, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012794, ts 909640455, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55296 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006810, ts 909640448, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55296 (type 00, seq 029695, ts 3658920178, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55302 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 024041, ts 3658920176, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55302 (type 00, seq 012795, ts 909640615, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55296 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 006811, ts 909640608, len 000170)
        Got  RTP packet from    192.168.40.48:55296 (type 00, seq 029696, ts 3658920338, len 000160)
        Sent RTP packet to      192.168.40.48:55302 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 024042, ts 3658920336, len 000170)
```

Comment: Have you check the logs in browser console? System audio volume?

Comment: Is this a programming or networking question?

Comment: You need to share your Javascript code html markup.